# mysql check account type to see if admin on login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, admin

hi in my script i have it logging in users , but i want to have the script also check if the user is an admin by seeing if the account_type is a,b,c account type "c" is the admin and i would like it to redirect the admin to the admin page ...

```
<?php // Start Session to enable creating the session variables below when they log in

// Force script errors and warnings to show on page in case php.ini file is set to not display them
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

include_once("security/checkuserlog.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['idx'])) {

echo '<script language="Javascript">';
echo 'window.location="home.php"';
echo '</script>';
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Initialize some vars
$errorMsg = '';
$username = '';
$pass = '';
$remember = '';
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        $remember = $_POST['remember'];
    }
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $pass = stripslashes($pass);
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);

    // error handling conditional checks go here
    if ((!$username) || (!$pass)) { 

        $errorMsg = '<font color="red">Please fill in both fields</font>';

    } else { // Error handling is complete so process the info if no errors
        include 'connect_to_mysql.php'; // Connect to the database
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); // After we connect, we secure the string before adding to query
        //$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass); // After we connect, we secure the string before adding to query
        $pass = md5($pass); // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable they supplied after filtering it
        // Make the SQL query
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' AND password='$pass'"); 
        $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        // If login check number is greater than 0 (meaning they do exist and are activated)
        if($login_check > 0){ 
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){


                    // Create session var for their raw id
                    $id = $row["id"];   
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                    // Create the idx session var
                    $_SESSION['idx'] = base64_encode("g4p3h9xfn8sq03hs2234$id");

                    $username = $row["username"];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;



                } // close while

                // Remember Me Section


                // All good they are logged in, send them to homepage then exit script
                header("location: home.php"); 
                exit();

        } else { // Run this code if login_check is equal to 0 meaning they do not exist
            $errorMsg = '<font color="red">The Username And Password did not match.</font>';
        } 


    } // Close else after error checks

} //Close if (isset ($_POST['uname'])){
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at PHP's MySQLi extensions - there are a lot of Bad Things that come with the old mysql_* functions. Also, you should probably salt your `md5` hash, for safety.

Answer (score 1):

`if ($row["account_type"] == "c") { header("Location: admin.php"); };` in your `while` loop should do it.

This will basically set the "Location" header to "admin.php" or whatever admin page you want, however don't forget to check in your admin page if the user is actually logged in, to avoid users simply going manually to "admin.php" and bypassing the permission check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$account_type= $row["account_type"];
$_SESSION['account_type'] = $account_type;
```

then change `header("location: home.php");` into

```
if($account_type=='admin')
{
   header("location: adminpanel.php");
}
else
{
   header("location: home.php");
}
```